# How to annotate nullability correctly for by-reference field setter?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable-reference-types

I've got a fairly standard implementation of a base class to simplify implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which provides a standard implementation for raising the PropertyChanged event from property setters only if the new value is actually different from the previous value.

```
public abstract class PropertyChangeNotifierBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
      if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
      field = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
      return true;
    }
}

public class PropertyChanger : PropertyChangeNotifierBase
{
    private Foo _foo;

    public Foo FooProperty
    {
         get => _foo;
         set => SetField(ref _foo, value);
    }

    public PropertyChanger(Foo fooValue)
    {
         FooProperty = fooValue;
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me [warning CS8618](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8618)#nonnullable-reference-not-initialized) which complains that the `PropertyChanger` constructor doesn't set the value of the `_foo` field before it finishes. This looks like a false positive, since the constructor *does* set the wrapping property `FooProperty`, which calls into `SetField()`, which should set the value of `_foo`. Since the field and property are both typed as non-nullable Foo, shouldn't this guarantee that `_foo` is non-null after the property setter runs?

What annotations should I be adding to `FooProperty` and/or `SetField<T>` so that the property setting is properly analysed? Or, is the compiler's analysis correct, and I should instead be changing the behaviour of the code to *ensure* that `_foo` is initialised?

I tried adding `[MemberNotNull(nameof(_foo))]` to the `PropertyChanger` property. I thought that would inform the compiler that `_foo` will be non-null after the property is set, but that just *changes* the warnings. I instead get *three* warnings:

```
    [MemberNotNull(nameof(_foo))]
    public Foo FooProperty
    {
         // On _foo: CS8613, possible null reference return; CS8774 - Member must have a non-null value when exiting
         get => _foo;
         // On _foo: CS8610, possible null reference assignment
         set => SetField(ref _foo, value);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you assume it's a false positive? `SetField` will return immediately if both the value and field are null, leaving the field null

Comment: I think `private Foo _foo = default;` should be enough.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, you mean `default!`. This will [indeed](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQo2n0) fix the warning.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I thought that since the *property* is typed as non-null, it should never receive `null` as an input value, and therefore the `SetField` method should be guaranteed to set the field to a non-null value.

Comment: Yes, warning fixed. In the case where a `Foo` property is actually `IFoo` (interface type rather than concrete type) I found it necessary to use `IFoo _foo = null!;` rather than `IFoo _foo = default!;` but that does do the trick. Please feel free to write a proposed answer.